# Python 3.2 - Converting words to lower case & number of palindromes in the list of words that have at least 3 letters

Tags: python, return, return-value, python-3.2, palindrome

I have a random file of words and some of them are palindromes and some are not.  Some of those palindromes are 3 or more letters long.  How do I count them?  I'm wondering how to make the conditions better.  I thought I could just length but I keep getting 0 as my answer, which I know is not true because I have the .txt file.
Where am I messing up?

```
number_of_words = []

with open('words.txt') as wordFile:
    for word in wordFile:
       word = word.strip()
       for letter in word:
           letter_lower = letter.lower()

def count_pali(wordFile):
    count_pali = 0
    for word in wordFile:
        word = word.strip()
        if word == word[::-1]:
            count_pali += 1
    return count_pali

print(count_pali)

count = 0
for number in number_of_words:
    if number >= 3:
       count += 1

print("Number of palindromes in the list of words that have at least 3 letters: {}".format(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good right up until the loop:

```
for number in number_of_words:
    if number >= 3:
        count += 1
```

There is a problem in the logic here. If you think about the data structure of number_of_words, and what you are actually asking python to compare with the 'number >= 3' condition, then I think you will figure your way through it nicely.

--- revised look:

```
# Getting the words into a list
#    word_file = [word1, word2, word3, ..., wordn]
word_file = open('words.txt').readlines()

# set up counters
count_pali, high_score = 0, 0
# iterate through each word and test it

for word in word_file:

    # strip newline character
    word = word.strip()

    # if word is palindrome
    if word == word[::-1]:
        count_pali += 1

        # if word is palindrome AND word is longer than 3 letters
        if len(word) > 3:
            high_score += 1

print('Number of palindromes in the list of words that have at least 3 letter: {}'.format(high_score))
```

NOTES:
count_pali:   counts the total number of words that are palindromes
high_score:   counts the total number of palindromes that are longer than 3 letters
len(word):    if word is palindrome, will test the length of the word

Good luck!

Comment: Hm... I'm comparing it to the previously defined/found palindromes.
But how do I call them back so I can use them in this loop and make them equal to my condition of length? I know that the length of my palindromes has to match the number length but I'm unsure how to write that.

Comment: Ok no worries. If I understand your code correctly:

the count_pali() function will count the total number of palindromes, by incrementing by by every time a palindrome is found.

and... you also want to count how many of these palindromes are more than 3 letters long.

so, could you try an if statement directly after your test for palindrome? In pseudocode, it would look a little like this:

# your preceding code here...
if word is palindrome:
    count_pali + 1

Comment: adding more to last comment:


'# your preceding code here...
if word is palindrome:
    count_pali + 1
    if word is longer than 3 letters:
        long_word + 1'

Are we closer?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "long word".  You're suggesting I do another if loop inside my if loop that checks if a word is a palindrome right? I did that and this is my loop now:
`def count_pali(wordFile):
    count_pali = 0
    for word in wordFile:
        word = word.strip()
        if word == word[::-1]:
            if word >= 3:
                count_pali += 1
    return count_pali
        
print("Number of palindromes in the list of words that have at least 3 letters: {}".format(count_pali))

`
But it still doesn't give me an answer! Is my return function wrong?

Comment: Hi, no worries here. We will see if we can get a little closer to what you want. Will modify the answer above shortly

Comment: Hi Nick - so I used the code you posted above but it returns the result of 0.  I'm guessing it's because of the same problem I had when I made number_of_words = [], and in your code count_pali and high_score are 0.  Also, I replaced all the "words" with each_word because the code you posted says for "each_word" in word_file.
Lastly, I replaced 
`if len(count_pali) >= 3:
            high_score += 1`
I'm sorry for all the questions!  I'm just really trying to see what I am doing wrong with my conditions in loops and count.
Thanks again!

Comment: For above I replaced `if len(word)' which with `if len(count_pali)`

Comment: Hi, how is it coming along, any positive progress? It looks like you might have a few problem areas. Looking at your first code:    A) number_of_words is an array, every time you find a palindrome longer than 3 letters, you would need to append the word to the array. B) the counter, count_pali, simply counts the number of words that are palindromes, not the length of the word, so len(count_pali) will not evaluate. BUT... len(word) will give you the length of the word. And you are very right, I have mixed up each_word and word - very silly of me, will revise. :)

Comment: Just tested and ran with the following test words: '>>> word_file
['theht\n', 'fiveevif\n', 'notthisone\n', 'tat\n', 'tut\n', 'swataws\n']', and it seemed to run well.

Comment: I finally got it! And thanks for letting me know about my initial code, I thought number_of_words would just give me the freedom of getting any value.
Finally - if I'm supposed to include any number that is of length 3 or more would I be correct to change `if len(word) = 3:` to `if len(word) >= 3:` and that would then give me the total number of all words that are 3 or more letters long?
Thanks so much for all your time and answers and going back and telling me what was wrong with my initial code too!

Comment: Hey, that is fantastic! Glad it is going for you know. And yes, completely agree with you about changing `if len(word) >= 3:`.

Comment: The numeric answer isn't what the number value is supposed to be (it returns Boolean values) even though `if len(word) = 3:` results in 56 and  `if len(word) > 3:` and `if len(word) >= 3:` gives me 108, which is 56+52.  It's sort of ridiculous at this point but again thanks for your time&patience!

Comment: Getting a cumulative total like 56 + 52 sounds like there is an issue around the order that things are being run. Is it possible that the counter is incremented 56 times (ie. there are 56 palindromes) and then the SAME counter is being incremented again for the longer words (i.e. there are 56 total palindromes, 52 of which are >= 3 --> 56 + 52 = 108)? You would either want to use two different counter variables, or only bother to count the longer words.

Comment: It's because I forgot to convert it into all lowercase letters.
This is what I added to your code from my initial code yet it still returns 108.
`word = word.strip()
    for letter in word:
           letter_lower = letter.lower()`

Comment: nice one with the lower: try this to simplify it: `word = word.strip().lower()` will clean up the code a little and make it runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through `number_of_words` in order to calculate `count`, but `number_of_words` is initialized to an empty list and never changed after that, hence the loop

```
for number in number_of_words:
    if number >= 3:
        count += 1
```

will execute exactly 0 times

Comment: That makes sense.  For some reason I thought giving the list the value of [] would just mean it's able to be any number. Is there a way to do that?  Or what should I be looping through? It can't be count_pali cause that's a function and wordFile doesn't seem to work as well even though I opened it again like this:
`with open('words.txt') as wordFile:
    count = 0
    for number in wordFile:
        if number >= 3:
            count += 1`

Comment: do it in steps - first try to create a list of all the words, then create a function that tests for whether a word is a palindrome, a function to check whether it has more than 3 characters, etc. Test these functions.

Comment: Thanks! But how do you create a list of all words?  The words I'm referring to are specifically the ones in the .txt file I'm opening in the beginning.  I made another if loop to test for both conditions and only return it then
`def count_pali(wordFile):
    count_pali = 0
    for word in wordFile:
        word = word.strip()
        if word == word[::-1]:
            if word >= 3:
                count_pali += 1
                return count_pali
        
print("Num of pals with 3 lets: {}".format(count_pali))`
I'm sorry but I'm really confused about this!

Comment: ``if word >= 3`` should be ``if len(word) >= 3``

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it might help to understand some of the problems that we have run into here. Mostly, you can see how to add to a list, and hopefully see the difference between getting the length of a string, list and integer (which you actually can't do!).

Try running the code below, and examine what is happening:

```
def step_forward():
    raw_input('(Press ENTER to continue...)')
    print('\n.\n.\n.')

def experiment():
    """ Run a whole lot experiments to explore the idea of lists and
variables"""

    # create an empty list, test length
    word_list = []
    print('the length of word_list is:  {}'.format(len(word_list)))
    # expect output to be zero

    step_forward()

    # add some words to the list
    print('\nAdding some words...')
    word_list.append('Hello')
    word_list.append('Experimentation')
    word_list.append('Interesting')
    word_list.append('ending')

    # test length of word_list again
    print('\ttesting length again...')
    print('\tthe length of word_list is:  {}'.format(len(word_list)))

    step_forward()

    # print the length of each word in the list
    print('\nget the length of each word...')
    for each_word in word_list:
        print('\t{word} has a length of:  {length}'.format(word=each_word, length=len(each_word)))
        # output:
        #    Hello has a length of:  5
        #    Experimentation has a length of:  15
        #    Interesting has a length of:  11
        #    ending has a length of:  6

    step_forward()

    # set up a couple of counters
    short_word = 0
    long_word = 0

    # test the length of the counters:
    print('\nTrying to get the length of our counter variables...')
    try:
        len(short_word)
        len(long_word)
    except TypeError:
        print('\tERROR:  You can not get the length of an int')
    # you see, you can't get the length of an int
    # but, you can get the length of a word, or string!

    step_forward()

    # we will make some new tests, and some assumptions:
    #     short_word:    a word is short, if it has less than 9 letters
    #     long_word:     a word is long, if it has 9 or more letters

    # this test will count how many short and long words there are
    print('\nHow many short and long words are there?...')
    for each_word in word_list:
        if len(each_word) < 9:
            short_word += 1
        else:
            long_word += 1
    print('\tThere are {short} short words and {long} long words.'.format(short=short_word, long=long_word))

    step_forward()

    # BUT... what if we want to know which are the SHORT words and which are the LONG words?
    short_word = 0
    long_word = 0
    for each_word in word_list:
        if len(each_word) < 9:
            short_word += 1
            print('\t{word} is a SHORT word'.format(word=each_word))
        else:
            long_word += 1
            print('\t{word} is a LONG word'.format(word=each_word))

    step_forward()

    # and lastly, if you need to use the short of long words again, you can
    # create new sublists
    print('\nMaking two new lists...')
    shorts = []
    longs = []
    short_word = 0
    long_word = 0

    for each_word in word_list:
        if len(each_word) < 9:
            short_word += 1
            shorts.append(each_word)
        else:
            long_word += 1
            longs.append(each_word)

    print('short list:  {}'.format(shorts))
    print('long list:  {}'.format(longs))
    # now, the counters short_words and long_words should equal the length of the new lists
    if short_word == len(shorts) and long_word == len(longs):
        print('Hurray, its works!')
    else:
        print('Oh no!')

experiment()
```

Hopefully, when you look through our answers here, and examine the mini-experiment above, you will be able to get your code to do what you need it to do :)